# code do not called the other else conditional statment on unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, artificial-intelligence, raycasting, navmesh

I created a program in unity that uses an array of transform for the position for Ai that will move point to point once done it will restart from zero again.

I also made another program that shoots a ray cast, and when it detected an enemy it will stop the patrol program and enable the navmesh agent else its will turn on the patrol script and turn off the navmesh agent, but the last part wasnt working for some reason i need help knowing why its not working

heres the code for the patrol

```
    public Transform[] Points;
    public int current;

    public NavMeshAgent agent;

    public milkscript milk;
    public float speed;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        current = 0;

        agent.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if(milk.chasing == false) 
        {
            agent.enabled = false;

            Patol();
        }
        if(milk.chasing == true) 
        {
            agent.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    public void Patol() 
    {
          if(transform.position != Points[current].position) 
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,Points[current].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else 
        {
            current = current+1 % Points.Length;
        }

        if(current == 8) 
        {
            current = 0;
        }
    }
```

and here the code for the raycasting

```
    NavMeshAgent Agent;

    public Patrol patrol;

    public bool chasing;


    public Transform enemy;

    public Transform[] Points;

    [SerializeField] LayerMask layermask;

    public Transform Point;

    public float raydistance = 10f;

    public float enemyview = 5f;
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
         chasing = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
            if(Physics.Raycast(Point.position, Point.forward, out var Hit, raydistance, layermask)) 
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(Point.position, Hit.transform.position, Color.red);
            
            Debug.Log(Hit.transform.name);
        
            if(Hit.transform.name == "Chocltaemilk") 
            {
                chasing = true;
                patrol.enabled = true;
                Agent.SetDestination(Hit.transform.position);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            Agent.enabled = false;
            Debug.DrawRay(Point.position, Point.forward, Color.green);
            patrol.Patol();
        }

        if(chasing == false) 
        {   
            Agent.enabled = false;
            patrol.enabled = true;
        }
         
        if(chasing == true) 
        {   
            Agent.enabled = true;
            patrol.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void returen() 
    {
        chasing = false;
        patrol.enabled = false;
    }

    public void ChasePlayer(Transform target)
    {
        Agent.SetDestination(target.position);
        transform.LookAt(target.position);
    }
```

Comment: I suppose you should fix the typos, one of them is the problem, probably `"Chocltaemilk"`

Answer (score 0):

That may mean that you are always hitting something with:
`Physics.Raycast(Point.position, Point.forward, out var Hit, raydistance, layermask)`

For the else to happen when you hit something else, you can try to re-arrange your brackets `{}` like so:

```
void Update()
{
    if(Physics.Raycast(Point.position, Point.forward, out var Hit, raydistance, layermask)) 
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(Point.position, Hit.transform.position, Color.red);
        
        Debug.Log(Hit.transform.name);
    
        if(Hit.transform.name == "Chocltaemilk") 
        {
            chasing = true;
            patrol.enabled = true;
            Agent.SetDestination(Hit.transform.position);
        } else {
            Agent.enabled = false;
            Debug.DrawRay(Point.position, Point.forward, Color.green);
            patrol.Patol();
        }
    }

    if(chasing == false) 
    {   
        Agent.enabled = false;
        patrol.enabled = true;
    }
     
    if(chasing == true) 
    {   
        Agent.enabled = true;
        patrol.enabled = false;
    }
}
```